# Changing the dimension (axis) of the dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, axis

I know the community hate people uploading a image, but it is hard to explain without showing the dataframe I have.
[image]

is there any way that I can group the data by the columns 'Open','High','Low','Close','Adj Close','Volume' ,'Symbol' like this:
[image]

Have been browsing through pandas documentation for days and tried plenty methods but still dont work. Thank you and sorry for uploading image.

Update:
The code for the df is as following:

```
import yfinance as yf
stock_df = yf.download(["AAPL","GOOG"], start="2020-05-19", end="2020-05-20", interval='1m',group_by='ticker')
stock_df
```

need to pip install yfinance first tho. Hope this could help you guys to test it thanks. group_by = can be deleted so now stock are group by the column. However they are still separated, you can see there is 12 columns in there where 6 of them are repeated, any way to add a Symbol Column like what my expected output? Thanks

Comment: `df.stack(level=0)`?

Comment: I agree with @QuangHoang but unsure how you get your values out of `AACG` if the original frames are `NaN`s.

Comment: Have you any reason to post png non copyable images instead of text that others could use to reproduce and test? If you posted copyable text, I could try to answer...

Comment: @SergeBallesta hi Serge i have added the code, should be able to test it now. Thanks

Comment: @r.ook NaN value will be dropped in later process so no need to worry if they exist for now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
df.rename_axis(('Symbol', None), axis=1).stack(level=0).reset_index(level=1).sort_values('Symbol')
```

Though I am unsure how your `AACG` rows have data when your original frame are `NaN`s.

Comment: This worked! How can I remove the index of date? do i do another .reset_index(level=0, drop=True) ?